# My Joomla component not displaying anything

Tags: joomla, components, joomla2.5, joomla-component

I have build my own component. I know very well about these stuff but all of sudden I wonder that the joomla request to my custom component is not displaying anything. Its displaying blank page.
See this:
http://designsoft.bestplacestestserver.com/index.php?option=com_marketplacemanager

Here is the very initial code of 'marketplacemanager.php' file of component where the request is not arriving. Don't know why.

**Code - marketplacemanager.php**

> defined('_JEXEC') or die;
>
> jimport('joomla.application.component.helper');
>
> echo 'aa'; exit;  // should have something displayed as here

Comment: check your error log, and also check [tutorial how to create mvc component in Joomla](http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_Component/2.5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been resolved. Actually MVC naming pattern or something else was wrong. I didn't properly renamed my existing component that I was reusing.

Answer (score 2):

Go to global configuration. On the server tab turn error reporting to development. Reload the page. Most likely you will now see the error.

Comment: Thank you for the assistance. I have sorted out the problem. Actually there was an unknown MVC problem. I created new component and it worked correctly :)

Comment: Oh my this is so useful. I didnt know this option was available, I finally understood what was wrong with my component code. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this, replace the first line of your code with:

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die('why is blank?');
```

If still does not show anything it means displaying errors on your server is locked, so checking the error log would be the only option.

Comment: No actually nothing was working:) Even the first line was not being displayed. I checked the naming conventions and every thing was ok.
But actually where was some MVC naming problem or something else.

I just created new component and it worked correctly. I was little careful this time and it worked :) 

Thank you for all your assistance :)